# Re-Render on componentWillReceiveProps(nextprops)

Tags: react-native

Is their is any other way to re-render the component if `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)` has changed other than `this.setState({})` or `this.forceUpdate()`.

```
 ComponentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
     if (this.props !== nextProps) {
      //something here
    }
   }
```

Comment: ComponentWillRecieveProps wont cause a rerender anyway.  Have a look here to find the method that works for your use case:  http://busypeoples.github.io/post/react-component-lifecycle/